# Unable to access an element using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am new to Selenium. I am trying to use Python to

1. Type a particular piece of text (name of company) in the textbox of the following website: https://www.screener.in/
2. Download all the concall transcripts available near the bottom of the following webpage: https://www.screener.in/company/RELIANCE/consolidated/

However when I try to inspect element of the transcript button, I am unable to find an id or name that I can use to reference to them. Is there another method to download them using selenium? More generally, is there a better way of solving both 1 and 2?

The code I am trying for another website is as follows:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.bseindia.com/')

input_element = driver.find_element("name", 'q')

input_element.send_keys('reliance industries ltd')

input_element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

time.sleep(15)

driver.quit()
```